# Why does Angular2 require CORS when loading main.js from foreign server?

Tags: iis-7, angular, cors

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://otherwebsite.com/myapp/app/main.js.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://otherwebsite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

when referencing a main.js file in Angular2:

```
System.import('http://otherwebsite.com/myapp/app/main')
```

But no other .js files require CORS pulled from the other site.

I know how to add [CORS support for Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for methods but this is not a method.  I know how to add [CORS support for Apache folders](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) in .htaccess files.  And with a little digging I found how to add [IIS 7 CORS folder support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18122239/84424) that made this error go away.

Buy why would Angular2 need CORS for my main.js when all the other .js files loaded without CORS issues?

Comment: External js files are a restricted resource and require CORS headers. This would apply to all scripts not just angular. The error is coming from the browser. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post a plunk reproducing this?

Comment: @drewmoore I did the Angular 2 [Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) , but linked all Javascript code from a different url.  The oddity was Angular 2 loaded fine from the other site without CORS, but when it tried to load my code (main.js) it failed with CORS errors.

Comment: Wait, so you your main.js is coming from one server and everything else is coming from a different one? If so, then the "oddity" is simply that the latter server included the appropriate CORS headers but the former (the one serving your stuff) did not

Comment: Open chrome dev tools -> network tab, expand one of the requests from each server, and compare the headers in them

Comment: @drewmoore all Javascript is coming from the foreign server, including Angular's and my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is loaded from another domain (which even means a different IP port) than `index.html` was initially loaded, then the server you request a file from, needs to provide the CORS headers, otherwise the browser won't allow to fetch it.

Comment: I just thought it was odd that only my javascripts required CORS when all the JavaScript came from the other site without CORS fine.