# How to enable CORS for a directory in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have ASP.NET MVC hosted on `api.example.com`. also I've stored some images in `api.example.com/images` directory.

When I try to access those images from `example.com`, I get a CORS error on my client.

If it was a controller, I would use this attribute to enable CORS:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

But how can I enable CORS for a directory like `/images` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122239/how-do-i-add-cors-headers-on-a-per-folder-basis-on-iis) You could create a web.config for each directory that you want to allow CORS for.

Comment: Please don't answer with a link to another question. Instead, flag the question as a duplicate of that other question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey They don't get the ability to vote to close [until 3k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @Amy I didn't say "vote to close", I said "flag". They get the ability to flag as a duplicate [at 15 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah, okay.  Fair enough.